# SDCard/SSD: is it possible to make it last longer, make it more reliable? and how?

Tags: ssd, sd-card, lifespan

So, I read old sdcards wear out after many uses.

Then I was thinking... my 32GB sdcard could last much longer if I formatted it to, lets say (24GB or must be 2^n? like 16GB?).

So, when it's blocks start becoming bad, the unused blocks would be allocated automatically for usage.

That is how SSD already works right?

or... I am wrong and it is not possible, or will not be that automatic at all? or that is unnecessary?

Comment: SSD's have specific firmware in their controllers to manage this, I don't believe SD cards are quite as sophisticated. In general, SD cards and other removable storage cards are considered disposable.

Comment: SD card controllers already do the basic bad block replacement.  What they lack compared to an SSD (besides higher quality chips), is wear leveling and some other features.  You won't extend its life by formatting it as you describe because the spare blocks are preassigned (it won't start using advertised capacity to replace bad blocks).  SD cards are designed around being cheap and disposable.  Other than avoiding applications involving massive writing, there really isn't anything you can do to extend its life except be careful not to lose it.

Answer (score 2):

Interesting question.

You're spot on that SSDs can indeed work around bad blocks and sectors in this way due to the memory controllers they possess - standard flash drives are considerably simpler though and are far less likely to possess the error correcting code required (as far as I know).

Think about this from another perspective though:
In your example you have a 32GB SD card.
Sure, you could 'split it in half' and work with 16GB until the *eventual* time enough bad sectors appeared to cause problems, then use the 'other half'.
**BUT**, if you just left it as one 32GB card, it would require twice the number of bad sectors to reach the fail point (assuming the sectors are of the same size), because the card is twice the size of those split in half.

Ergo *it's not the size of the card, it's the rate at which faults occur*

Anyway, I can't say exactly how operating systems would treat such a situation but it's certainly true that when blocks and sectors go bad the overall capacity drops. Honestly though, you're more likely to lose the darned thing or for it to go obsolete before you actually hit the data write limit.